# In an IPv4 packet header, exactly what does the 11 byte security option '2' signify?

Tags: ip, packet, ipv4, datagram

The only information I can gather is that it is 'an option provided for the military to indicate the security classification of IP datagrams'. What is meant here by the 'security classification'? And what is this used for, more specifically?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1108

Comment: Thank you very much